# Matplotlib combining datapoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this dataframe:
[image: Dataframe]

I would like to plot the movies in order, but when I tried it looks like this:
[image: plot]

How do I plot this dataframe without combining movies that are listed twice? (ie- "Top Gun: Maverick" and "Avatar: The Way Of Water)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `data2['Film]` to `y` inside [`ax.barh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh.html), you can pass a range of consecutive numbers, and then set the values of `data2['Film']` as the yticks using [`ax.set_yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html). E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'Film': ['Film A', 'Film B', 'Film A', 'Film D'],
                      'Weekend_gross': [1, 3, 7, 5]})

data2 = data2.sort_values('Weekend_gross')

clrs = ['teal', 'orange', 'cyan', 'violet']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))

# create a range with length of your data
idx = range(len(data2))

# pass `idx` to `y` param
ax.barh(idx, data2['Weekend_gross'], 
        color=clrs, edgecolor='black')
ax.set(title='What movie Grossed the Most in 1 Weekend', 
       ylabel='Film')

# set `yticks` with `Film` column
ax.set_yticks(idx, data2['Film'])
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: result bar]

Of course, if you don't mind resetting your index, you can just use `data2.index` for this. E.g.:

```
# reset index:
data2 = data2.sort_values('Weekend_gross').reset_index(drop=True)

...
# pass as `y`
ax.barh(data2.index, data2['Weekend_gross'], 
        color=clrs, edgecolor='black')

...
# and set yticks
ax.set_yticks(data2.index, data2['Film'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`barh`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html) from Pandas:

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'Film': ['Top Gun: Maverick', 'The Batman', 'Top Gun: Maverick'],
                      'Weekend_gross': [1, 2, 3]})

data2 = data2.sort_values('Weekend_gross')

clrs = ['r', 'orange', 'chartreuse']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
data2.plot.barh('Film', 'Weekend_gross', color=clrs, legend=False, title='What movie Grossed the Most in 1 Weekend', ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]